# Redoc content is not rendering in angular application

Tags: angular, redoc, redocly

I'm trying to integrate Redoc into my Angular project, and it seems that Redoc content is not rendering.

Here is what I have done so far:

**angular.json**

```
    "scripts": [
      "src/assets/js/redoc.standalone.js"
    ]
```

The component I am testing on

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


declare var Redoc: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initDocs();
  }


  initDocs(){
    Redoc.init('http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json', {
    scrollYOffset: 60,
    hideDownloadButton: true
    }, document.getElementById('redoc'))}

}
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Dashboard</span>
</mat-toolbar>


<p>
  dashboard works!
</p>
```

test

**Screenshot Dashboard page**

[image]

**Console - Logs**

[image]

**console rendered html structure**
[image]

Comment: where is `document.getElementById('redoc')`

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I have added a screenshot so you can view the rendered dom

Comment: Add the following to your index.html page in the body section <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc@next/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"></script> as mentioned in - https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/issues/1454#issuecomment-867349073

Comment: @AjinathJedhe  actually I was folllowing the instructions from that link but that is not working

Comment: Move initDocs in ngAfterViewInit i have tried locally and it is working for me with Angular 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**solved last week**] After conducting my research and not finding any solutions, I pondered why not utilize **ElementRef** from **'@angular/core'**; to query the selector by id. To my surprise, this approach worked. To save others the trouble of searching for a solution, here is what I did to integrate Redoc into my Angular application:

**Install redoc via npm**

```
npm i redoc
```

[Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redoc)

**Add redoc scripts to angular.json**

```
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/redoc/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"
    ]
```

**Your component (in my case dashboard.component.ts)**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var Redoc: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit  {
  
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initDocs();
  }


  initDocs(){
    const container = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#redoc');
Redoc.init('http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json', {
    scrollYOffset: 60,
    hideDownloadButton: true
  }, container);
  
  }

}
```

This example uses Angular's ElementRef to access the native DOM element and the **ngOnInit** lifecycle hook to ensure that the component is ready before initializing Redoc.

**Optional:**
You can create a service:

```
// redoc.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare const Redoc: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RedocService {
  initDocs(specUrl: string, options: any, container: HTMLElement): void {
    Redoc.init(specUrl, options, container);
  }
}
```

**Use the Redoc Service in a Component:**

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { RedocService } from './redoc.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  template: '<div id="redoc"></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private redocService: RedocService, private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initDocs();
  }

  private initDocs(): void {
    const redocContainer = document.getElementById('redoc');

    if (redocContainer) {
      this.redocService.initDocs('http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json', {
        scrollYOffset: 60,
        hideDownloadButton: true
      }, redocContainer);
    }
  }
}
```